# Python 3.3.3 Code Help. Calories remaining

Tags: python

```
     print("Are you male or female?")
     gender = input()
     print("How old are you?") 
     age = input() ``
     print("How many calories have you eaten today?")
     calories = input()
     if age in range(10-15) and gender == (Male):     
         print(2230 - calories)
```

This is the beginning of a code I have been trying to write where someone enters their gender, age and calories that they have eaten. I have been given data by my teacher that shows the amount of calories that each age group and gender should be eating. You then minus the calories they have eaten with the value they should be eating depending on their age and gender. It is very simple so the only age groups included are 11-14 and 15-18. The questions all run fine, but I can't get the main part of the code to run. It is on Python 3.3.3

Comment: `gender == (Male)`. That doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make following changes to your code.

```
 print("Are you male or female?")
 gender = input().lower()
 print("How old are you?") 
 age = int( input() )
 #convert input to int

 print("How many calories have you eaten today?")
 calories = int( input() )
 #convert input to int
 if age in [ x for x in range(10,15)  ] and gender == "male":     
     print(2230 - calories)
```

Comment: `[ x for x in range(10,15)  ]`? Why not just `if 10 < age <15?

Comment: @MorganThrapp . +1 for your suggestion. Indeed that's much better.

Answer (score 0):

You've got quite a few issues in your code. One, when you try to compare the value you get as age/calories, you're not converting them to ints first, and you can't compare an int and a string. Also, `gender == (Male)` compares the variable `gender` to the variable `Male`.

Here's a cleaned up version:

```
 print("Are you male or female?")
 gender = input()
 while True:
     try:
         age = int(input("How old are you?"))
     except ValueError:
         print('Please enter a number for your age')
         continue
     else:
         break

 while True:
     try:
         calories = int(input("How many calories have you eaten today?"))
     except ValueError:
         print('Please enter a number for your calories eaten today')
         continue
     else:
         break

 if (10 < age < 15) and gender == 'male':     
     print(2230 - calories)
```